# Safety of a forced diacetyl test

Tags: lager, safety, diacetyl-rest

I'm brewing a lager and did a forced diacetyl test similar to the one found here - https://spikebrewing.com/blogs/ask-a-pro/an-easy-diy-diacetyl-test

OSHA recommends less than 25 ppb for short term inhalation exposure (https://www.osha.gov/flavorings-related-lung-disease).

This article states that homebrew can have diacetyl up to 1 ppm - https://byo.com/article/brewing-science-controlling-diacetyl/

My beer had a ton of diacetyl shown during the test and also from taste. So my question is how much risk is there in a forced test every now and then?

Comment: You might get some more informative answers the Chemistry Stack exchange. This is brewing related but the expertise needed to answer is more of a chemical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSHA standard is an inhalation warning of pure diacetyl in air.  You're measuring diacetyl in a liquid.  Its very different saftey-wise.  As long as you aren't aerosolizing your samples and inhaling it you're fine.

Comment: What about if the sample boils? Does that affect anything especially since the boiling point of diacetyl is slightly lower than water?

Comment: The amount of daicetyl is pretty low I think you're going to be fine.